# UIDatePicker breaks when using UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, uidatepicker

I'm creating an app with Monotouch 5 and I'm having a problem with creating a datepicker with the mode UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime on iOS 4.3 or lower when running my app in an iPad Simulator. The DatePicker is always broken, although the dimensions I set for it's frame and the surrounding view are perfectly fine.

This is how it looks like on an iPad Simulator with iOS 4.3:

http://screencast.com/t/isIRcUcKCF5

and this is how it looks on an iPad Simulator with iOS 5.0:

http://screencast.com/t/UxPTpR0Btzb

This problem does not occur on iPhone Simulators or real devices. I know it also does not occur on real iPad devices with iOS 5, but I could not test 4.3 or lower because I have no such device.

The source code for creating the date picker is as follows:

```
public override void Selected (MonoTouch.Dialog.DialogViewController dvc, UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath path)
        {
            var vc = new MyViewController (this) {
                Autorotate = dvc.Autorotate
            };
            datePicker = CreatePicker ();
            datePicker.Frame = PickerFrameWithSize (datePicker.SizeThatFits (SizeF.Empty));
            //vc.View encompasses the entire, screen so there is plenty of space available for the date picker                           
            vc.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
            vc.View.AddSubview (datePicker);
            dvc.ActivateController (vc);
        }


public virtual UIDatePicker CreatePicker ()
    {
        var picker = new UIDatePicker (RectangleF.Empty){
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth,
            Mode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime,
            Date = DateValue,
        };

        return picker;
    }

    static RectangleF PickerFrameWithSize (SizeF size)
    {                                                                                                                                   
        var screenRect = UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame;
        float fY = 0, fX = 0;

        switch (UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation){
        case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
            fX = (screenRect.Height - size.Width) /2;
            fY = (screenRect.Width - size.Height) / 2 -17;
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
            fX = (screenRect.Width - size.Width) / 2;
            fY = (screenRect.Height - size.Height) / 2 - 25;
            break;
        }
        // calculated values:
        // fx: 224
        // fy: 369
        // size.Width: 320
        // size.Height: 320
        return new RectangleF (fX, fY, size.Width, size.Height);
    }
```

When I am using a datepicker with the modes UIDatePickerMode.Date or UIDatePickerMode.Time, the problem does not occur.

The problem looks just like [blank UIDatePicker on iPad in mode UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846534/blank-uidatepicker-on-ipad-in-mode-uidatepickermodedateandtime), but the fix described there does not work in my case for some weird reason.

Any hints on how to work around this bug would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't have a clue how to make the code above work, but I managed to work around this iOS bug by using a UIPopupView for displaying the calendar instead.