# how to show UIDatePicker in iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uidatepicker

I implemented the `UIDatePicker` in iPhone and it's working correctly.

The same code I tried with iPad but it is not showing me `UIDatePicker`.

I read somewhere that I need to show it with `UIPopOverController` and find [this](http://omegadelta.net/2010/06/04/ipad-simulator-crashes-if-a-uidatepicker-is-in-a-uipopovercontroller/)
 link but it is not showing the proper code.

I can't make a separate XIB for that.  I have to implement it by code itself.
Mine is IOS5.

I use the following code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag == 1)
    {
            [self showDatePickerIniPad];
      }
}
   -(void)showDatePickerIniPad
 {
     UIViewController *popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
     UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
     popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300);
     [popoverView addSubview:datePicker];
     popoverContent.view = popoverView;
     popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 244);

     UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
     [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

     txt_FromDate.inputView = datePicker;
 }
```

Comment: Check my Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7343106/815179

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is more on the lines of learning rather than a specific doubt or question, i am posting tutorial links. These 2 tutorials should solve your problem(s) -

[UIPickerView Basics](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_4_iPad_Multiple_Component_UIPickerView_Example_%28Xcode_4%29)

[UIDateView Components](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_the_UIPickerView_and_UIDatePicker_Components_in_iOS_4_iPad_Applications_%28Xcode_4%29)

**UPDATE:** Also check these highly relevant links from stackoverlfow itself -

[UIDatePicker in UIActionSheet on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941583/uidatepicker-in-uiactionsheet-on-ipad)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830585/uidatepicker-inside-uiactionsheet-ipad

[blank UIDatePicker on iPad in mode UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846534/blank-uidatepicker-on-ipad-in-mode-uidatepickermodedateandtime)

Comment: In your example UIDatePicker is put in XIB, I have to show it on UITextField click.I did code for iphone but picker not being shown in ipad

Comment: I used the code of 1st link. But I didn't get how can I set it show on textfield click.I used for iphone `txtbox.inputview=datePicker` but for UIPopViewController I wont be able to use that

Answer (score 0):

If you want the popover to show when you click on the textfield you are doing in the right method, `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`.The problem is this is a Delegate Method for the textField so you should include the `UITextFieldDelegate` in you interface in the .h file

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>{
```

and set the delegate of you text field like this

```
self.yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

That should solve your problem.